# Why is this code slower?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Just updating my code to be Rails 3 ready, however I'm experiencing a major performance issue with the code below.

**Old code (nice and quick)**

```
@products = Product.all(
                        :order => 'name',
                        :include => [:category, :brand, :merchant]
                       ).paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

**New code (10 x slower)**

```
@products = Product.order("name")
                   .includes([:category, :brand, :merchant])
                   .paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

I added the line breaks for easy reading.

I'm using Postgres for my DB, maybe this is the issue?

Any other tips to make this code better will be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried it in production mode?

Comment: No just development - have I made any mistakes with the syntax?

Comment: Development mode is not necessarily optimized for speed. This could very well be some debugging hooks or convenience features. If there's no obvious reason for it to be slow, I would at least try it outside of development.

Comment: If you think it's a problem with the database you need to post the generated SQL code for both solutions. Then you can also run both statements in psql and compare their runtime. If that is not different, then it's a problem im Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check the outputted SQL (from logs or the console) to see if something's changed and/or how the query might be optimized.

Comment: Console looks fine, SQL looks ok. This is the first thing I checked

Comment: What exactly is 10x slower then?

Comment: I asked what, not how much exactly. That particular line of code? If so, how did you measure it?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be a problem with the pagination? Which plugin are you using for pagination? You might want to try Kaminari.